# How to use preg_replace for change variable names and values in another php/txt file

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have a little problem with the syntaxis for use preg_replace. I have a function that should replace in a  .php file the values of many variables (like a config file).

Example:

file.php:

```
<?php
$var="string value";
?>
```

Function:

```
    function savedata($varname, $newvalue){
        $data = file_get_contents("file.php");
        $newdata = str_replace([find $varname="whatever";], $varname."=$newvalue;", $data);
        file_put_contents("file.php", $newdata);
    }
```

And if it runs should make the file to this:

```
<?php
$var="a new string value";
?>
```

I find

> preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', $str, $content)

But works for only the quoted value and if i try add $varname.'='... at start, i get various errors.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following which uses [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) and [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$data = '<?php
$var="string value";
?>'; # same as file_get_contents("file.php");

$varname = '$var';
$newvalue = 'a new string value';

$newdata = preg_replace('/('. preg_quote($varname) .'=")[^"]+(")/', "$1$newvalue$2", $data);

echo $newdata;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, when i tried with many variables the values got null, but with a little change in the remplace data `"$1$newvalue$2"`  to  `$varname."=\"".$newvalue."\""` now it works perfectly, regards!